# PayPal After checkout handling

Tags: cookies, paypal, session-cookies

I have a web service at which users can buy reports made on the fly using PayPals Express checkout process. I want to make sure that no matter how the user returns to the site (through paypals callback or by himself) he could download the report he payed for. For that I need to keep the report ID he has bought somewhere. Where and how would it be best to do that? (Cookies? Sessions Parameters?)

I am using ASP .Net C#.

Thanks,

Wess

Answer (score 0):

Do the users have logins that are managed by you in your database?  If so and you want the user to be able to return at any time to your page and download the report, then you'll need to use a PayPal callback to store in your database what report ID the user has purchased.

If you don't manage your users then I'm not sure how this can be accomplished because cookies are limited (and can be disabled by users) and sessions expire.